# why not use integral for averaging inductor current?

Tags: circuit-analysis, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, power-electronics, circuit-design

I am watching the video lesson on state space representation for dc-dc converter [here](https://youtu.be/fhBjfhidBSU?t=3401) (at 56:41).

I am a bit confused about the average inductor current expression there. 
 Why not using the integral to calculate average instead of the one used in the picture?

[image]

Comment: If you would do both calculations properly, you'd get the same answer. The average current **is** the area between the curve and the X-axis. If you calculate that like shown or use an integral is up to you. But since the current has a triangle/sawtooth shape, most people find this calculation easier to grasp.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I am familiar with the definition with integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current is assumed/approximated to be linear over time, and it's quite convenient to calculate the average this way.

Of course you can be the badass using integrals to calculate the average in this simple case, and if the function is not linear, you will definitely use integrals.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of average (in this sense) *is* the integral/time.

If those segments are assumed to be straight lines, then the average can be calculated much more cheaply as (Imax+Imin)/2.

If those segments are curved a bit (as they will be), then the average can still be approximated, closely enough to control the converter successfully, by (Imax+Imin)/2.

I am puzzled by the D and (1-D) terms, as you seem to be using them in an expression involving I2dT. Is the I2 constant, so suitable for simple multiplication by D and (1-D), or are they varying as in your sketch, so need integration over time? They are not needed for the straight line case.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand the question. However, for more detail, you can watch the video I mentioned above.